# Use the SameTask with task Id

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, task

I need to run same method for different list parameters. for example List X , List Y, etc. when method is started it never stops till application closed by user, as you can see below. My problem is that, on the runtime if I have list X, Foo method must be work as a different task, and by the way new items can be added to list on runtime, when method is working if new parameter is added to list X, I make sure new item of X goes to same method task. How to handle this with using task.CurrentId? is it possible to get a task currentId and send parameters to that certain task?

```
public void Foo(string name)
{
    while(true)
    {
        //some process
    }
}

GetNewParameter(String sample)
{
    if(someCase)
    {
        //if there is a foo method runing on X list on a different Task, I must add
        //and make sure to be new parameter is sent to Foo method working on already X 
        //List.
        X.Add(sample);
        //Task.Factory.StartNew(() => foo(sample));
        //Send to already running task
    }
    if(someCase)
    {
        //If there is no task working on Y list I need to create a new task to run Foo
        //method on it.
        Y.Add(sample);
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => foo(sample));
    }
}
```

Comment: Use some collection which you will be filling and the 'task' will be consuming. Producer-consumer pattern. Why is it so important for you to use the same task? And how do you want to use it actually?

Comment: Lists has different kind of strings, and each list's items related to each other, so if there is a method working on X list, the new items will be added to X list, I cannot create new task, it must be evaluated in same task which works already on X lists items.

Comment: ok, but imagine you had the task you wanted... how do you want to use it... once you have created it, you have no access to its action running...

Comment: Hmm. I understand, I got the idea, you mean i can not send any parameter to runnnig method, but is it possible to keep a list in method, for example list X in Foo, and i try to add new items to list for evaluating ? but of course same thing occur here, i make sure working method on runnung x list

Comment: exactly... Standard solution is to keep list of items to process and let the task loop and process the list... That way you can add new items in a runtime and stop the task after you have no new items to process.

Comment: just be sure to lock the resources properly... there is System.Collections.Concurrent namespace which have some very usefull collections for that.

Comment: Thank you,  Divisadero. Your ideas make me think little bit different, and producer-consumer pattern with locking is working fine now

Comment: @Divisadero Consider posting your suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to searching for Task and then manipulating it (scary and rather impossible), use Producer-Consumer pattern. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem

In short - in two separate threads you will produce inputs for the processing and in another one you will be processing them. Inputs for processing will be saved in thread safe collection (access to them must be under lock).

Processing thread should loop. It will look if there is any input to process, if yes, it will process it and look if it was not cancelled meanwhile. If there is nothing to process and it was not cancelled, it will go to sleep for a while and then it will check again.

*"is it possible to get a task currentId and send parameters to that certain task?"* For any function call there is no way to change arguments send to it after it is called. You can change the values of what the arguments reference to (add new item to list or change property of class) but there is no way of changing argument that are of value-type. These are copied and you have no further access to them from the caller.